# Drupal bootstrap running from command line

Tags: bootstrapping, drush

I am using Drupal 7 functions externally, and I followed [this tutorial](http://www.avenuewebmedia.com/drupalbootstrap-connect-drupal-external-php-script) for using Drupal functions externally; it works perfectly.

In test.php file I have loaded/included Drupal bootstrap.

When I run the script from command line (`php test.php`), it gives me the following error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'default_drupal' in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /data/var/www/html/mcsu_sites_test01/includes/lock.inc).

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Hello, and welcome on Drupal Answers. May you show the code you are using on test.php?

Answer (score 2):

You could also try [Drush](https://www.drush.org). Once you've installed it, you can `cd` into your drupal root then run `drush scr test.php`. In that file, all Drupal functions will be available.

Answer (score 1):

You need this section from `scripts/drupal.sh`:

```
// define default settings
$cmd = 'index.php';
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']       = 'default';
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']        = '/index.php';
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']     = '127.0.0.1';
$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] = NULL;
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']  = 'GET';
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']    = '';
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']        = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/';
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = 'console';
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `PDOException error` , probably your problem is in db conection . drupal **can not connect database** .
which version of drupal you are using ?

check $databases or $db_url variables(according your drupal version) and it's properties set correctly

if your are usning  Drupal 7

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'yourdatabase',
      'username' => 'usernameofdb',
      'password' => 'passwordofdbuser',
      'host' => 'dbhost', //localhost if you are localy worked
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
 );
```

or in drupal 6 in `settings.php` in default directory check

```
$db_url = 'mysql://username:password@localhost/databasename';
```